# How to get all elements with multiple classes in selenium

Tags: python, selenium

This is how I get the website

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = '...'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
```

Now I want to extract *all* elements with a certain classes into a list

```
<li class=foo foo-default cat bar/>
```

How would I get all the elements from the website with these `classes`?

[There is something like](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/elements/finders/#optimized-locator)

```
fruit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#fruits .tomatoes")
```

But when I do this (I tried without spaces between the selectors too)

```
elements = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".foo .foo-default .cat .bar")
```

I get

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: .foo .foo-default .cat .bar
> Stacktrace:
> WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:183:5
> NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:395:5
> element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:300:16

These are the `classes` I copied from the DOM`s website though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just the HTML

```
<li class=foo foo-default cat bar/>
```

You can remove the space and put a `.` to make a `CSS SELECTOR` as a locator.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.foo.foo-default.cat.bar")
print(len(elements))
```

or my recommendation would be to use it with explicit waits:

```
elements_using_ec = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.foo.foo-default.cat.bar")))
print(len(elements))
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: What import do you need for the `explicit waits` variation

Comment: You can find the imports above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried without spaces between class names?

```
fruit = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".foo.foo-default.cat.bar")
```

Comment: yes, same result

Comment: @Stophface Does your html actually have `<li class=foo foo-default cat bar/>` or is it `<li class="foo foo-default cat bar"/>`?

Answer (score 0):

There is an undocumented function

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".foo.foo-default.cat.bar")
                   ^
```

This works.